# NgModule layout brakes on mapping to abstract class

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm in a process of moving a huge app to `NgModule` layout and in that process I noticed that my provider mappings to abstract classes brake.

The thing is that I am using abstract classes as quasi interfaces (which are lost ar transpile time) to map injection providers. So I make some abstract class `AbstractService` (with abstract keyword and abstract methods) which them is mapped to `AbstractServiceImpl` which extends that abstract class and is accessed by interface defined in `AbstractService`. And it all worked just fine until now.

Now, as I try to run application who includes some sub modele that does what is listed above, I get a runtime error of `Unexpected token export` which is gone if I convert that class to being non abstract. And heres a plunker for it: http://plnkr.co/edit/JFa1N1pxRsoEgtNqhhaA?p=preview

So the question is - how come? And can it be overriden somehow. Just as this concept seems nice and stuff like that. And I'd gladly keep employing this concept.

Comment: The Plunker produces `run.plnkr.co/:20 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export(…)` which seems to be a TS issue rather than an Angular2 issue. I have seen it but don't know how to fix.

Comment: Might be so. But still, it wasn't there before I moved to `NgModule` layout. So it's at least sane to assume they have something in common.